# Laravel 4. Getting ID of current post

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm making comments system, but at the momement I'm facing problem I can't solve. I got two database tables, posts and comments (I already created relationships). I have to assign comments for unique post. So first of all, post root is

```
Route::get('/playlists/{slug}'...
```

I created my comment route like this:

```
Route::post('/playlists/{slug}'...
```

So in CommentController, whenever validator passes I save comment details to comments table like this

```
    $comment->content = Input::get('content'); 
    $comment->post_id = ???????
    $comment->save();
```

So how do I recognize in laravel 4.2 in which post I'm wrriting a comment? At the current post root i can reach data for current post from post table, but the problem is that it's in view file only. Maybe there is some way to pass data from view to controller? Could you give me short example of this technique? Thanks!

Comment: Is `{slug}` in your route the `post_id`?

Comment: No but it could be. Every post record has unique slug. I tried passing $slug into my CommentController's function, but couldn't get any results. On post comment button click url changes, for example:
    public/playlists/3JSNWz89PDXUH7Rki9K5dWagcxlGCX6P. On post comment button click it changes to: /playlists/%7Bslug%7D. Maybe i should look for mistake somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could handle this.

1. Pass via the route.  Your route could look like:

   ```
   Route::post('/posts/{post_id}/comments')
   ```
2. Pass via the post request.  Then you could access it like `Input::get('post_id')`.

Comment: My comments and post content is on the same page. It seems that second way fits my needs. So i should create invisible input in my form with value of post_id or do I read it directly from url? Sorry if it looks dumb, I'm still learning.

Comment: Totally understandable.  Right, you would have a hidden input in the "comments" form that would have the post_id.  Make sure you validate/verify the post_id send to the backend by the post (eg make sure the post exists, make sure the user has permissions to comment on that post) because you can't trust any input from the user (ie it is able to be forged).

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I just wonder, how would it look like, if i want to read {slug} variable from url?

Comment: Pass the `$slug` variable into the controller action function.  More details on how that works:  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers